# How to compress a Byte array without stream or system io

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I'm trying to encode an image into a byte array and send it to a server.
the encoding and sending parts wok fine but my problem is that the byte array is too large and takes too long to send so I thought compressing it would make it go faster. but the actual problem is that I CAN NOT use system.io or streams. and I'm targeting .net 2.0.
Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use system.io or streams out of curiosity? Are you using a different platform?

Comment: I'm coding for webgl and in webgl I can't use most of the .net libraries @rolls

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
```

code:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
        dstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        dstream.CopyTo(output);
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

---

**Updated**

Use 7zip library:
http://www.splinter.com.au/compressing-using-the-7zip-lzma-algorithm-in/

```
// Convert the text into bytes
byte[] DataBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OriginalText);

// Compress it
byte[] Compressed = SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.SevenZipHelper.Compress(DataBytes);

// Decompress it
byte[] Decompressed = SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.SevenZipHelper.Decompress(Compressed);
```

Comment: i used this 7Zip library but it doesnot find reference to SevenZipHelper . can you please help out ?

Comment: @pulkit The target framework (.NET version) does not match the .NET version build of the referenced 7Zip DLL. For example, your project is .NET 2.0, but the 7Zip DLL is .NET 4.0, or vice versa.

Comment: Is there a nuget lib for this?

Comment: I have tested the DeflateStream, my result was the more you have the same byte repeating, the more it can get compressed, the less you have, you may end up on sizes more than the uncompressed

Answer (score -1):

**Compress**

```
        public static byte[] Compress(byte[] inputData)
            {
                if (inputData == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("inputData must be non-null");

                MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
                {
                    dstream.Write(inputData, 0, inputData.Length);
                }
                return output.ToArray();
    }

OR



public static byte[] Compress(byte[] inputData)
    {
        if (inputData == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputData must be non-null");

        using (var compressIntoMs = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gzs = new BufferedStream(new GZipStream(compressIntoMs,
             CompressionMode.Compress), BUFFER_SIZE))
            {
                gzs.Write(inputData, 0, inputData.Length);
            }
            return compressIntoMs.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

**Decompress**

```
    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] inputData)
            {
                if (inputData == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("inputData must be non-null");

                MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(inputData);
                MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    dstream.CopyTo(output);
                }
                return output.ToArray();

                if (inputData == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("inputData must be non-null");
            }

OR

    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] inputData)
            {
                if (inputData == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("inputData must be non-null");

                using (var compressedMs = new MemoryStream(inputData))
                {
                    using (var decompressedMs = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var gzs = new BufferedStream(new GZipStream(compressedMs, CompressionMode.Decompress), BUFFER_SIZE))
                        {
                            gzs.CopyTo(decompressedMs);
                        }
                        return decompressedMs.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The op has stated that he can't use the System.IO namespace as he developing in another platform which don't have the library.