# How can I improve send/receive speed using TCP? C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm making a Remote Desktop application using TCP, I've tried/searched for many ways to capture the screen and send it but they all do the same thing.

**To Send:**

1. Capture the screen using Bitmap and the copyfrom method
2. Use memorystream to save the bitmap
3. Use TCP socket to send the bitmap serialized

**To Recive:**

1. Receive the message with readbytes method
2. Use memorystream to store the byte array
3. Use `Image.FromStream(memorystream)` to create a image

It works nice on LAN connection but when I connect with a remote server using VPN, the image takes 0.5 to 5 seconds to arrive

this is my code:

**DeskTop Class:**

```
internal static class Desktop
{
    public static Image TakeScreenShoot()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        try
        {
            using (Graphics Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                Graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            bitmap = null;
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static void SerializeScreen(Stream stream, Image Image)
    {
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        Image.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        int numBytes = (int)memory.Length;
        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        binaryWriter.Write(numBytes);
        binaryWriter.Write(memory.GetBuffer(), 0, numBytes);
        stream.Flush()
    }

    public static Image DeserializeScreen(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        int numBytes = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        byte[] buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(numBytes);
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        return Image.FromStream(memory);
    }
}
```

**Host class**

```
private void SendImage()
    {
        while (Status == ServerStatus.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                Image bitmap = Desktop.TakeScreenShoot();
                Desktop.SerializeScreen(_NetStream,bitmap);
            }
            catch
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

**Client Class**

```
protected void ReciveMessage()
    {
     while(Status == ServerStatus.Connected)
      {
        try
        {
            ImageRecibed?.Invoke(Desktop.DeserializeScreen(_NetStream));
        }
        catch
        {

        }
      }
    }
```

How can I improve my code to run faster?

here a [Video](https://youtu.be/QwC-IUb7t30) of the application speed

PD. I'm so new on this

Comment: Have you tried to compress data before sending it over network? I've used GZipStream for compressing message to be sent over message broker.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-6.0#examples

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got your mean correctly or not, but maybe using [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial) help you, serialize your images with it and then deserialize them in other side

Comment: Have you checked to see how large a single bitmap screen grab is? With no compression on a 1920x1080 display with full color that's **6 MB** worth of data.

Comment: You are really reinventing the wheel here. Good RDP software use compression, not just to actually compress a single bitmap, but to only send *changes* to the screen. Look at the MS-RDP protocol and try understand how that works

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a good question. My socket programming experience is very limited. But I can think of a simple way. If you reduce the size of the byte array by compressing it before sending, the performance will probably improve slightly.

here is a good example => [How to compress a Byte array without stream or system io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191950/how-to-compress-a-byte-array-without-stream-or-system-io)

After the packet leaves the LAN, many external factors come into play. For example, it can make a big difference whether the VPN server you use is paid or not, or where is the location of this VPN Server? is it close to you or not?, or what is the hardware power of the vpn server you are using? There are a lot of possibilities.

Also, using Udp instead of Tcp will cause a slight increase in performance too, because the packet size of Udp is smaller and no acknowledgment. So if you use Udp and compress it before sending, maybe you can get a suitable result but the problem here is reliability. Also, even if you use Udp and compression, I'm not sure that there will be a performance increase at the level you are aiming for.

Therefore, I hope someone who is an expert on this subject will give detailed information because I am very curious about it.

Comment: I would expect gzip and similar to have negligible effect on jpeg. Maybe a better image compression algorithm/reducing quality could help. The UDP part makes sense, it is generally used for streaming data. One more thing is to only send differences and synchronize once in a while to reduce the load. But that is a wholly different approach to what OP currently has.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Using keyframes like how most video codecs do is how every remote desktop system I've worked with has done it. It's why performance is flawless for so many activities, but as soon as you throw a video or other widespread animation on screen it gets super choppy.

Comment: @Logarr  I guess the real problem is when we send a video or animation, the frame rate problem comes into play because access rates of packets cannot keep up with an appropriate frame rate of video for the most part. I believe that's why it looks choppy. I wonder what kind of method is used and the video becomes very fluid. The easiest way is to send packages faster, but that's not easy either.

Comment: Yes, well, if the use-case is remote desktop, I don't think doing fluent animations should be the primary focus.

Comment: UDP (by and large anyway) means losing any benefit from stateless offloads like TSO - TCP Segmentation Offload.  That is something which allows TCP to send a template TCP/IP header and upwards of 64 KiB of data to the NIC in one trip down the protocol stack, and the NIC will segment that into correctly-sized segments.

Answer (score 0):

One of the common limits to the performance of a TCP connection is:

Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime

If things were "fast" on your LAN but slow through the VPN, I assume the use of a VPN means greater distance, which means RoundTripTime will increase.  And unless WindowSize increases accordingly, Throughput will decrease.  So, what you want to do is increase WindowSize.  How one does that will depend on the specifics of the OS/stack being used.